# simple hook function not working

Tags: wordpress

This is a function that fires after the user submits a gravity form in wordpress. Ive talked to their support team, and have gone thru adding a custom log inside the function, and from the systems report, the can tell the action is firing fin, but not the log inside the function. and i cant seem to find what is wrong with it.

I've tried adding the action inside an mu plugin, I've tried uninstalling all plugins, even tried a fresh install with only the gravity form plugin, and my modifications to the functions file.

Its a pretty straight forward function:

```
function survey_done( $entry, $form ) {
   $user_id = get_current_user_id();
   add_user_meta( $user_id, 'survey_complete', 'control' );
}
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_2', 'survey_done', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert the function you have shown then it might be due to the plugin loading first then gravity form plugin.

So, your hook will not be fired until the Gravity form plugin is loaded.

Comment: ive added the same exact code inside the function somewhere else and it works just fine.

Comment: the last option is for meta_value, doesnt just have to be true or false

Comment: anyways, i tested your code just in case, and it still didnt work. thanks for your help tho